# PHP include Statement Issue

Tags: php, html, css

I have a `menu.php` file I need included in each page on a site I am building. When I open the `menu.php` by itself it works fine. It's when I have it included in other files such as `index.php` then nothing loads.

Below is my `index.php` content. My `menu.php` is strictly html with a .css style sheet linked. I have searched and can find nothing to solve my problem. Any suggestions?

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: that is menu.php in the include, not header.php.

Comment: Are all your files within the same folder?

Comment: Yes they are. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: dose your index file extension is `.php` or `.html`?

Comment: all files are .php, including index.

Comment: @Akam - read the question again -- the answer to your question is there already.

Comment: Could you please add the code for `menu.php`, maybe it's not generating any output?

Comment: When you say "nothing loads", do you mean the include doesn't load, or the entire page doesn't load? Have you checked your logs?

Comment: @j08691: I just want confirm that!

Comment: You could try doing it like this `<?php include("menu.php"); ?>`. Put this at the top of your php page and then paste here what it says `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: @Vector - I'll try that when I get back to my PC. Thanks.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tried placing it into ("") and then calling error_reporting(0) and the page still loads blank. Maybe I'm calling it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain how directories work:

**ROOTFOLDER--**

home.html

contact.html

**PHPFOLDER---**

header.php

**CSS-----**

stylesheet.css

if in `home.html` you have `<?php include 'header.php';?>` that wont work because the header is in the **PHPFOLDER** so you must `<?php include 'folderphp/header.php';?>`

Answer (score -1):

Check your path, inclusion location etc.

For example, if a file located in a certain folder includes a file, that also includes another file.. the relative path is always based on the very original file opened.

What I do:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/menu.php'; // if file is at /public_html/menu.php
```

or

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/menu.php'; // if file is at /public_html/includes/menu.php
```

THat way no matter where you're opening from, you're calling an absolute path.

Comment: And don't forget to start file/folder path with the slash (/) after the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] because that variable stops at the folder name without trailing slash (/).

Comment: You really should get into the habit of using `__DIR__` instead of DOCUMENT_ROOT. This will allow you to run the site in a subdirectory for development purposes and won't make it dependent to server configuration.

Comment: Good advice Andrew. Will do.